# ¿Cómo saber si una palabra esta contenida en algún elemento de una sublista? (Python)

Tags: python, lista, bucle-for

Tengo `letters_list`, que a su vez tiene contenida otras sublistas, lo que quiero lograr es que si alguno de los elementos de la primer sublista de `letters_list` contiene la palabra `letters`, que en `result` se agregue el valor booleano de `flagTrue`, y si no encuentra `letters` en ningún elemento de la sublista, que en `result` se agregue el valor booleano de `flagFalse`, y así mismo con las demás sublistas, por lo que al momento de ejecutar `print('result = ', result)` el resultado en consola seria el siguiente `result = [True, False, True]`, ya que en la primer sublista si hay un elemento que contiene la palabra, en la segunda no hay ningún elemento que la contenga, y en el tercero si hay un elemento que tiene dicha palabra.

Lo que tengo de código es:

```
letters_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'just letters'],['1', '2', '3', '4' 'just numbers'],['d', 'e', 'just letters']]


def testList():
    
    result = []
    flagTrue = True
    flagFalse = False
    
    for i in range(len(letters_list)):
        for j in range(len(letters_list[i])):
            if letters_list[i][j].find('letters') >= 0:
                result.append(flagTrue)
            else:
                result.append(flagFalse)
    print('result = ',result)

testList()
```

Mas sin embargo con dicho bloque de código obtengo en consola lo siguiente `result =  [False, False, False, True, False, False, False, False, False, False, True]` lo cual no es la salida que espero, ya que según entiendo, hace la búsqueda por cada elemento de la sublista, y no por cada sublista de la lista como a mi me gustaría.

Espero que alguien me ayude, de antemano gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acá se aplicaría muy bien el uso de la built-in function `any()`. Con [esta función](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) puedes chequear si una condición es cierta al ser aplicada para al menos un elemento de un iterable.

En tu caso la condición sería si `'letters'` está incluída en alguna de las strings de las sublistas.

Y como la salida que deseas viene dada en forma de una lista, puedes usar una comprehensión de listas para ello.

```
letters_list = [['a', 'b', 'c', 'just letters'],['1', '2', '3', '4' 'just numbers'],['d', 'e', 'just letters']]
target_word = 'letters'
result = [
    any(target_word in string for string in sublist)
    for sublist in letters_list
]
```

`result` contendrá:

```
[True, False, True]
```

Comment: Anduve indagando con respecto a dicha función con el link que me diste y veo que los ejemplos son muy básicos, me tocara investigar mas para entender esta función hasta este nivel, te agradezco mucho el aporte, gracias.